# HTML5 video issues in FF 3.6.13 doesn't want to load video

Tags: firefox, html, video

I have an issue that I need help with. I have a video on my webpage that is done using HTML5  tag. For some reason it is not wanting to load the video. The spelling of the URL and file is correct. It was working but when I added more videos to the site (meaning I uploaded them to the server) and put up another page with the same video it is no longer wanting to load. I have tried to use the preload attribute but that doesn't seem to help. I also took the other page down and the videos worked again. Any suggestions?

Video HTML:

```
<table class="contentpaneopen">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="contentheading" width="100%">Smart Strip on TV</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="contentpaneopen">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<video style="border: 1px solid #000000;" preload="preload" controls="controls" width="218px" height="138px">
<source src="Video URL" type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="Video URL" type="video/ogg"></source>
<source src="Video URL" type="video/webm"></source> Your Browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.</video>
<p>Even Oprah knows the benefits of using a Smart Strip!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This only seems to happen in FF 3.6.13. the website is http://www.bitsltd.net if you would like to test it and see for your self.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the OGG source before the MP4 one.

**edit**
The video on that site worked fine for me on FF 3.6.13.

Comment: I figured something else out. It only seems to have issues when I enable another page of my site that also has the same videos on it. It seems like it won't let it load the video if it is on more than one page. It probably worked for you because when I stopped working on it yesterday I disabled the second page and the videos worked again. I cannot leave the second page enabled because this site is for a business and I don't want there to be issues like that. I thought I read somewhere that the mp4 should go first for people that view it on iPads but maybe I have that backwards?